# ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: java, jasper-reports, websphere, classcastexception, xerces

I get the below error when trying to deploy my application to Websphere.

> ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

If I exclude the `xml-apis` dependency I get the below error.

> NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl

The application uses the below.

- Websphere 8.5
- Java 7
- jasperreports 6.1.0

Note: I have already changed the classloader settings on Websphere to below.

1. Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)
2. Single class loader for application

Comment: Do you happen to have the stack of the NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: Also... do you really need parent-last class loading? It's pretty rare that you need to use your own JAXP/JAXB implementation, and using parent-first would almost certainly eliminate this issue (since everything would delegate to parent loaders, all versions of the XML classes would come from a consistent class loader).